# Do I install 32 or 64 bit windows program on wine if I have Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit?

Tags: windows, wine, 17.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I was installing Wine 2.0 on Ubuntu 17.10 but I was wondering if I have to install 32-bit windows program or 64-bit if I use Ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: The answer is "It depends on the way you configured Wine"  Default is to match the system architecture, but Wine actually recommends setting up a 32-bit wine environment and use 32bit apps, as 64bit apps tend to have some... issues...

Answer (score 0):

WINE installs both architectures. So you can make 32-bit and 64-Bit prefixes. However, 32-bit is better supported by WINE.

Thus in most cases, the 32-bit version of the windows programs have a better success rate than the 64-bit versions. That said, it does not mean that 64-bit versions won't work.